# Having trouble with typeahead/predictive test functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/) and I decided to implement a "typeahead" kind of feature that Google has. Something like this:

[image: img1]

To realize this, I wrapped the `MTableEditField` component with my own, which looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MTableEditField } from "material-table";

const CustomTableEditField = props => {
  const [rawValue, setRawValue] = useState(props.value);
  const [suggestedValue, setSuggestedValue] = useState("asdasda");

  const handleOnChange = value => {
    // ... logic to find best match and set state values
  };

  return (
    <MTableEditField
      inputProps={
        suggestedValue
          ? {
              style: {
                backgroundColor: "#557D92",
                color: "white",
                padding: "offset"
              }
            }
          : {}
      }
      {...props}
      value={suggestedValue ?? rawValue}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomTableEditField;
```

The problem is that when there is a value, it looks like:

[image: img2]

I don't want it to change the whole background if there will be a match. I want it to keep the already-typed text, with suggested text appended to it.

I looked into gradients, which are treated as images that can be resized, but I wasn't able to get anything to render.

Is this possible to do at all, or am I just wasting my time?

## Edit

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cznyx1)

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: A https://stackblitz.com/ would be great

Comment: Sure, I've updated the OP

Comment: In your stackblitz, its showing the background, even there is not a match, is the code working typeahead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the customization of `MTableEditField`, But you can try some thing like following by writing own component.


1) The main idea is split the words (raw and suggestion) and keep them separate `span` elements so that we can get full control of the styling.

2) Wrap the `span` elements in `div` and write the own `onChange` event handlers.


PS: this is sample code, Will need to fine tune the code.

Check out the [working sample on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jcnoej)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const dict = ['apple', 'mango', 'berry'];

const CustomTableEditField = props => {
  const [rawValue, setRawValue] = useState("");
  const [suggestedValue, setSuggestedValue] = useState("");

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    // console.log('key: ', event.key);
    let new_raw;
    if (event.key === "Backspace") {
      new_raw = rawValue.slice(0, rawValue.length - 1);
    } else {
      new_raw = `${rawValue}${event.key}`;
    }
    setRawValue(new_raw);

    const suggested = dict.find(word => word.startsWith(new_raw));
    if (suggested && new_raw) {
      setSuggestedValue(suggested.slice(new_raw.length));
    } else {
      setSuggestedValue("");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      tabIndex="0"
      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
      style={{border: '1px solid green', height: '30px', color: 'black'}}>
      <span>{rawValue}</span>
      {suggestedValue && (
          <span 
            style={{backgroundColor: "#557D92",
            color: "white",
            padding: "offset"}}> {suggestedValue} </span>
      )}
      </div>
  );
};

export default CustomTableEditField;
```